# What is the quickest way to remove empty NSStrings from an NSMutableArray?

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsmutablearray

I have an `NSMutableArray` with `NSStrings` for items. Some are blank. What is the quickest way to find and remove the blanks without having to resort to looping, comparing to @"", etc.

Thanks,
Doug

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray *test = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"",@"",@"test",@"test1", nil];
[test removeObject:@""];
```

Comment: @Alladinian Ah - `removeObject` uses `isEqual`; my bad.

Answer (score 0):

```
[a filterUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
    [evaluatedObject length] != 0;
}]];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [NSPredicate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/Reference/NSPredicate.html) for doing this.

```
NSArray *myFilteredArray = [yourArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"length > 0"]];
```